# Wii controllers disconnect

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, wiimote

When I turn on my Wii, and I press any button on any controller, it connects properly.

If I press a button on any other controller, any other controller which was already connected loses connection, and the recently turned on controller never connects. After this I can connect controllers only after a reboot.

Every time I want to play with friends I have to only turn on one controller, go to the game, and when we're all ready to play, go to Wii Menu > Reconnect, and connect all the controllers pressing 1+2, then exiting the Wii Menu.

If a controller is not used for some time, it automatically turns off, and if someone presses a button on that controller, it disconnects all others and the Wii needs a reboot.

Have you heard of this problem before?

Does someone know how to fix it?

---

Info: My Wii is softmodded but this problem existed before I softmodded it.

Comment: That has never happened to me. I'd say you should get your Wii fixed, but considering the console has been discontinued, that might be difficult to do. If buying a new console is an option, the Wii U supports all Wii games including Wii accessories; just don't expect to play NGC games on it, it won't.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Video explaining it, just skip to about 42 seconds in:

My recommendation would be first of all make sure the batteries are fresh in every remote, then after having done that look on the Wii next to the disc slot there should be a hinged door open it and press the red button this will disconnect all remotes then where you put the batteries in press the small red button in it this should sync up the remotes and it should all work fine.

Comment: If this method does not work, is there any other way?

Comment: I believe there is not aside from getting the Wii seen by a tech professional.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. 
I've not only done this several times, but also followed the instructions on how to clear synced controllers and then I synced all four again. 
I'd like to add that my Wii is softmodded but this problem existed before I softmodded it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have ANOTHER remote then on the connected one press the home button then click on the remote on screen and press th buttons it tells you to do

Comment: if you read the description you would know that I am able to connect 4 controllers using the 'Home Button' (Wii Menu) > Reconnect, and then use 1+2 on each controller. But this is not the intended behaviour of the Wii, one should be able to turn on any controller at any time and have it connect without de-syncing all others.